# SQL SELECT which create column and use function to compare data in 2 tables

Tags: sql

A function that prints SELECT data that I compare with two tables. Writes to the column 'INFO' - 'It's good' or 'It's not good'. It has a comparison or discount in one table is the default, checking it with the second table is not the default.

I do not know how to explain it: /

Someone will help?

It's something about SELECT CASE? Or what?

Comment: For questions seeking help with SQL, always mention what RDBMS you are using (by an appropriate tag). I suspect most RDBMSs have a CASE style expression, which will give you some way to have a field's value be based on a condition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all break your question in two parts

1. you want to compare columns belogs to different tables
2. you want to get some coded result as above comparision

If my breakdown is correct, answer is below( in mysql ver )

*assume that you have table1(id, col1, col2) , table2(id, col3, col4) and compare col1 + col2 and col3 + col4*

1. join two tables

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` AS a INNER JOIN `table2` AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

2. getting encoded results

```
SELECT *
       ,CASE
           WHEN a.`col1` + a.`col2` > b.`col3` + b.`col4` THEN "It's good"
           WHEN a.`col1` + a.`col2` < b.`col3` + b.`col4` THEN "It's not good"
           ELSE "It's same"
        END AS `INFO`
FROM `table1` AS a INNER JOIN `table2` AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I do this with "SELECT column1, column2, IF(statement, 'text if is true', 'text if is not true') AS newColumn", but now i can do ELSEIF for this. How do this?

Comment: If you use IFELSE like function, you can make above `CASE ... WHEN` condition with combine nested IFELSE function. for example IF(c1, 'first true', IF(c2, 'true2','not true'), 'else'). you can combine as many as you need